# CANopen CiA 401 input polarity

Tags: embedded, can-bus, canopen

I'm trying to implement the CiA 401(I/O). But I don't know how the device should behave if the object 6002 (input polarity) changes.
Should the value in object 6000 (read input) also change and if so, a PDO should also be sent, although nothing has changed at the physical input?

Comment: This should be answerable by looking at the 401 spec itself.  And if not, an email to CiA would net you a better answer than anything we can provide.  They've been responsive to my group's questions on 443...

Comment: Ok thx, i will do so. I didn't find the answer in the spec.

Comment: It might be wise to get your hands the CiA CANopen conformance tool software, which you can use to stress test your application against CANopen conformance in general, as well as DS-401 conformance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only mandatory input polarity objects are 6002:0 and 6002:1, and it should affect the polarity of the corresponding digital on/off objects objects mapped at 6000. Note that DS-401 lists an "Entry Category" which dictates which objects and indices that are mandatory and which that are optional.

If you map the input polarity, it will be a RPDO in your application, and affect whatever TPDO that 6002 is mapped into. As far as I remember, the values inside 6000 should not change, only the values of the relevant TPDO. This TPDO will only be sent when it should - that is, depending on how it is configured: cyclic, on change, on request etc.